# Combine join and exists on join table

Tags: mysql, join, not-exists

I'm stuck solving this sql puzzle, I almost figured it out but the last part is a bit challenging.

I have a campaigns table and a users table

a campaign has a status: active / inactive.

On top of that there is a join table between campaigns and users: campaign_users. This table is used to exclusively assign a campaign to a subset of users.

Given this data:

```
Campaigns
id  name        status
1   campaign_a  active
2   campaign_b  active
3   campaign_c  active
4   campaign_d  inactive

Users
id  name
1   user_a
2   user_b
3   user_c

Campaign_users
id  campaign_id     user_id
1   2               1
2   3               2
3   4               1
```

I want to make a query that combines a few 'facets'. As I said I'm stuck at the last part here are my steps:

**Step 1: Select active campaigns:**

```
SELECT campaigns.* 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.status = 'active'

output
campaign: 1,2,3
```

**Step 2: (and) are not exclusively assigned to anyone:**

```
SELECT campaigns.* 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.status = 'active'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * FROM campaign_users WHERE campaign_users.campaign_id = campaigns.id)

output:
campaign: 1
```

**Step 3: (and) are exclusively assigned to the passed_in user_id (1).**

```
SELECT campaigns.* 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.status = 'active' 
INNER JOIN campaign_users ON campaign_users.campaign_id = campaigns.id 
AND campaign_users.user_id = 1

output:
campaign: 2
```

**Last step:**

This is the part where I'm stuck.

query to combine all 'facets' together: Only active campaigns that are not exclusive (assigned to no one) and are exclusive to the passed in user_id.

Writing this it feels like a bit of a contradiction, but an inner join only returns campaigns that are present in the join table, but it skips the 'non exclusive' campaigns.

```
expected output:

with passed_in user_id of 1

campaign: 1,2 (Active & non exclusive and exclusively assigned to user 2)

with passed_in user_id of 2

campaign: 1,3 (Active & non exclusive and exclusively assigned to user 2)

with passed_in user_id of 3

campaign: 3 (Active & non exclusive but no exclusive assigned to user 3)
```

Comment: Your problem stems from joining when there is no need to. Don't join when you don't have to. Conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause not in the `FROM`/`JOIN` clause. To get the exclusive campaigns for a user you'd usually use an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause (pseudo Code: "where  exists an entry for the user"). The final query would then combine the two conditions with `OR`: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...) OR EXISTS (...)`. In your case however you can use a simpler technique. Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple trick: outer join all `campaign_users` to the `campaigns`. You'll get a row per campaign and user for exclusive campaigns and a row with user null for non-exclusive campaigns. Keep all campaigns for either the user in question (say user 1) or all users (user null).

```
select c.*
from campaigns c
left join campaign_users cu on cu.campaign_id = c.id
where c. status = 'active' and (cu.user_id = 1 or cu.user_id is null);
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want! So the trick was in using another type of join? Could you elaborate why this works? Is it just because of the join or also the `cu.user_id = 1 or cu.user_id is null` ?

Comment: Um well, I thought I explained this in my answer... If you don't know outer joins yet, look them up. They give you all rows an inner join would plus rows from the first table that have no match in the second. So we generate a list of campaign-user associations where user null means "all users". In the where clause we pick the records fur user 1 and those for "all users" (thus eliminating only the exclusive-campaign-user associations for other users). Try it without the where clause to see the intermediate result and what we'll keep and what we'll dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` the queries for Step 2 and 3 to get the required result, e.g.:

```
SELECT campaign_id
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.status = 'active'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * FROM campaign_users WHERE campaign_users.campaign_id = campaigns.id)

UNION 

SELECT campaign_id
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaigns.status = 'active' 
INNER JOIN campaign_users ON campaign_users.campaign_id = campaigns.id 
AND campaign_users.user_id = ?
```